# ¿Cómo mantener expandido un menu despues de refrescar la página?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, local-storage, menu

Tengo un menú con opciones dentro y al dar clic en una opción me carga la página (refresca) pero el menú vuelve a su estado original, se contrae.

¿De que forma puedo dejar el menú expandido después de dar clic a una opción?
Probé con localStorage pero no sé como implementarlo adecuadamente

-- CODIGO DEL MENU VERTICAL (menu_vertical.php) --

```
    <?php
    #LIBRERÍAS
    require ("../includes/header.php");
    ?>
    
    <div class='nav-vertical'>
        <div class="dashboard-nav">
            <nav class="dashboard-nav-list">
                <div class='dashboard-nav-dropdown'><a class="dashboard-nav-item dashboard-nav-dropdown-toggle">
                    <i class="fas fa-chart-pie-alt"></i> Reportes</a>
                    <div class='dashboard-nav-dropdown-menu'>
                        <a href="test1.php" class="dashboard-nav-dropdown-item"><i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i>Test1</a>
                        <a href="test2.php" class="dashboard-nav-dropdown-item"><i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i>Test2</a>
                        <a href="test3.php" class="dashboard-nav-dropdown-item"><i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i>Test3</a>
                        <a href="test4.php" class="dashboard-nav-dropdown-item"><i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i>Test4</a>
                        <a href="test5.php" class="dashboard-nav-dropdown-item"><i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i>Test5</a>
                        <a href="test6.php" class="dashboard-nav-dropdown-item"><i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i>Test6</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class='dashboard-nav-dropdown'><a class="dashboard-nav-item dashboard-nav-dropdown-toggle">
                    <i class="fas fa-chart-pie-alt"></i> Reportes 2</a>
                    <div class='dashboard-nav-dropdown-menu'>
                        <a href="testX1.php" class="dashboard-nav-dropdown-item"><i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i>TestX1</a>
                        <a href="testX2.php" class="dashboard-nav-dropdown-item"><i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i>TestX2</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <?php 
    #SCRIPTS
    require ("../includes/footer.php");  
    ?>
```

-- CODIGO DE LA VISTA PRINCIPAL (index.php)

```
<?php
#MENU VERTICAL
require ("menu_vertical.php"); 
?>

<body>
  <img src='../images/Welcome.jpg'>
</body>
```

-- CODIGO DEL FOOTER (footer.php) --

```
<script src="../../includes/2022/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
  //EXPANDIR EL MENU
      $('.dashboard-nav-dropdown-toggle').click(function(){
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        if(parent.hasClass('show')) { 
          parent.removeClass('show'); 
        } else {
          parent.addClass('show');
        }
      }); 
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Has modificado la pregunta incluyendo otro menu desplegable que está utilizando las mismas clases. Esto modifica ligeramente la respuesta inicial. Haz estos cambios sobre tu código:

En el HTML ponle un ID a cada elemento de este tipo:

```
<div class='dashboard-nav-dropdown'>
```

de tal modo que sean únicos, por ejemplo:

```
<div class='dashboard-nav-dropdown' id="menu1">
```

Y en el javascript pon esto:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  //EXPANDIR EL MENU
  $('.dashboard-nav-dropdown-toggle').click(function() {
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    if (parent.hasClass('show')) {
      parent.removeClass('show');
      localStorage.setItem("expandirMenu", "false");
    } else {
      parent.addClass('show');
      localStorage.setItem("expandirMenu", "true");
      localStorage.setItem("menuId", parent.attr('id'));
    }
  });

  if (typeof localStorage.getItem('expandirMenu') !== 'undefined' && localStorage.getItem('expandirMenu') !== null) {
    if (localStorage.getItem('expandirMenu') == "true") {
      $('#' + localStorage.getItem('menuId')).addClass('show');
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

### Explicación de los cambios

- Se ha agregado un atributo **id** con un valor único en cada elemento `div` que contiene la clase **dashboard-nav-dropdown** que servirá para después referenciarlo en el código javascript.
- En el javascript, dentro de la función **click** para el selector de clase **dashboard-nav-dropdown** se ha establecido una variable del tipo *localStorage* denominada **expandirMenu** que almacena un valor booleano `true` o `false` según el menú está abierto o cerrado.
- En el caso de que además esté abierto, se ha establecido otra variable del tipo *localStorage* denominada **menuId** que permite almacenar el **id** del elemento pulsado, para después, en caso de refresco de página, saber cual de ellos debe mostrarse abierto.
- Fuera del evento click, se ha creado un condicional que comprueba si la variable localStorage con la clave **expandirMenu** ha sido creada, y en caso afirmativo, y si su valor es **"true"**, entonces agregamos la clase **show** al elemento **div** con el **id** coincidente con la clave **menuId** de *localStorage*.

Comment: Funciona perfecto. Pero tengo un problemilla, quizá deba editar la pregunta. Tengo mas opciones con la clase **dashboard-nav-dropdown-toggle** , es decir En el menú tengo la opcion Reportes y otra opción Reportes2, al dar clic en cualquiera si se mantiene expandido, pero expande todos.

Comment: Acabo de modificar mi respuesta, echale un ojo a ver si así te vale. (aunque creo que va a ser que no, pues ahora se te abriran independientemente pero al refrescar solo se mantendrá abierto el último, y seguramente querrás modificar ese comportamiento de nuevo)

Comment: ¿Cómo no va a funcionar? ¡Claro que funciona! y es justamente el resultado que esperaba.

Realmente eres un genio, Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda